# LALR(1) empty list of parameters for functions

Tags: parsing, grammar, lalr, lemon

I have a simple LALR(1) grammar, but I'm encountering a problem.

```
start ::= spec.
spec ::= MOD STRING top_stmt.
spec ::= top_stmt.
top_stmt ::= stmt.
top_stmt ::= conditional.
stmt ::= expr.
stmt ::= assignment.
conditional ::= IF stmt_list.
expr ::= retval.
expr ::= NOT retval.
retval ::= access.
retval ::= invoke.
access ::= ns_identifier OBJECT_OPERATOR property_chain.
access ::= ns_identifier.
ns_identifier ::= identifier.
ns_identifier ::= ns_identifier NS_SEPARATOR identifier.
ns_identifier ::=.
property_chain ::= property_chain OBJECT_OPERATOR identifier.
property_chain ::= identifier.
identifier ::= VARIABLE.
identifier ::= STRING.
assignment ::= access ASSIGN expr. [ASSIGN]
stmt_list ::= stmt.
stmt_list ::= stmt_list COMMA stmt. [COMMA]
invoke ::= access LPAREN empty_stmt_list RPAREN.
empty_stmt_list ::=.
empty_stmt_list ::= stmt.
empty_stmt_list ::= empty_stmt_list COMMA stmt. [COMMA]
```

The dot marks the end of the rule, terminals between brackets have associativity assigned to them: ASSIGN is right-associative, COMMA is left-assoc.

But [lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) says it can't reduce the rule "empty_stmt_list ::=." because it's not connected to the start symbol. I bet it is :-)

There is also a parsing conflict for "invoke", it cannot decide between RPAREN and COMMA when empty_stmt_list is indeed an empy list of statements.

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to parse function calls which have no (void) parameters.

Everything else works as expected.

Thanks

**Edit**: I have edited my original post and posted the entire stripped down grammar.

Comment: Your notation is not entirely conventional - is it ANTLR-inspired?  What are the parenthetical '(A)' and '(B)' stuff?  What is the significance of the lone '.' in the notation?  It seems to be a metacharacter indicating end of rules and what follows is action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first problem is that I don't think this bit does what you want it to:

```
invoke ::= access LPAREN empty_stmt_list RPAREN.
empty_stmt_list ::=.
empty_stmt_list ::= stmt.
empty_stmt_list ::= empty_stmt_list COMMA stmt. [COMMA]
```

The `invoke` production will match `access LPAREN COMMA stmt RPAREN`, which I assume is not desirable (and is where the LPAREN/COMMA conflict is coming from).

You can fix that by doing it like like this, which makes use of your existing `stmt_list` rule:

```
invoke ::= access LPAREN maybe_empty_stmt_list RPAREN.
maybe_empty_stmt_list ::= .
maybe_empty_stmt_list ::= stmt_list.
```

That still reports a conflict (but only 1 now) and still complains that `maybe_empty_stmt_list ::=.` can't be reduced.  So, looking in the XXX.out file to see what it is:

```
State 2:
...
     (16) ns_identifier ::= *
...
     (25) maybe_empty_stmt_list ::= *
...
                        RPAREN reduce 25  ** Parsing conflict **
....
                     {default} reduce 16
```

...it appears that the problem is with the `ns_identifier ::=.` rule.  Working back through the productions involved, it's not too difficult to see that an empty `ns_identifier` can be reduced to `stmt_list` (via `ns_identifier` -> `access` -> `retval` -> `expr` -> `stmt` -> `stmt_list`).

That explains the conflict; and fact that the `ns_identifier ::=.` rule is favoured in this case because it appears earlier in the grammar (see the rules for resolving reduce-reduce conflicts in the [documentation](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/lemon.html) explains why it complains that the `maybe_empty_stmt_list ::=.` rule can never be reduced.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I fixed it altogether, including removing the empty ns_identfier rule which was actually an artifact to solve another older problem. Notes to self: designing language parsers needs care and the "do it right" mentality. Accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding precedence rules for LPAREN/COMMA and check if it affects the semantics in other places.